# Terraform. How to identify element (key) using for_each

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-elb

I'm building AWS Network LB with target groups. And I stuck on `aws_lb_listener` adding several `target_group_arn` in several `http_tcp_listeners`
I.e. I have two `aws_lb_target_group` for 80 and 443 ports and two `http_tcp_listeners` for these same ports.

But I have got this error message:

```
in resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp":
│  172:       target_group_arn = each.value.arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is map of string with 4 elements
│ 
│ This map does not have an element with the key "arn".
```

```
variable "aws_lb_target_group" {
  description = "aws_lb_target_group"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    http = {
      name                 = "http"
      target_type          = "instance"
      port                 = 80
      protocol             = "TCP"
      protocol_version     = "HTTP1"
      type                 = "source_ip"
      enabled              = false
      path_health_check    = "/health.html"
      matcher_health_check = "200" # has to be HTTP 200 or fails
    },
    https = {
      name                 = "https"
      target_type          = "instance"
      port                 = 443
      protocol             = "TCP"
      protocol_version     = "HTTP2"
      type                 = "source_ip"
      enabled              = false
      path_health_check    = "/health.html"
      matcher_health_check = "200" # has to be HTTP 200 or fails
    }
  }
}

variable "http_tcp_listeners" {
  description = "aws_lb_listener"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    http = {
      port        = "80"
      protocol    = "TCP"
      action_type = "forward"
      alpn_policy = "HTTP1Only"
    },
    https = {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "TCP"
      action_type = "forward"
      certificate_arn = "data.terraform_remote_state.acm.outputs.acm_certificate_arn"
      alpn_policy     = "HTTP2Preferred"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "main" {
  for_each         = var.aws_lb_target_group
  name             = "test-group-${random_pet.this.id}-${each.value.name}"
  target_type      = each.value.target_type
  port             = each.value.port
  protocol         = each.value.protocol
  protocol_version = each.value.protocol_version
  vpc_id           = local.vpc_id

  stickiness {
    type    = "source_ip"
    enabled = false
  }

  health_check {
    path                = each.value.path_health_check
    port                = each.value.port
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
    interval            = 30
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main,
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp" {
  for_each          = var.http_tcp_listeners
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = each.value.port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  certificate_arn   = data.terraform_remote_state.acm.outputs.acm_certificate_arn
  alpn_policy       = each.value.alpn_policy

  dynamic "default_action" {
    for_each = aws_lb_target_group.main

    content {
      type             = "forward"
      target_group_arn = each.value.arn
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main,
    aws_lb_target_group.main,
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dynamic blocks, your key is not `each`, but the name of the block. So I think it should be:

```
target_group_arn = default_action.value.arn
```

To have only one default_action, try:

```
  default_action {
      type             = "forward"
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[each.key].arn
  }
```

Comment: Marcin thank you! This resolved my issue, but I have got the new related to AWS.

```
Error: error creating ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:.....): ValidationError: There must be exactly one action
...
  with aws_lb_listener.frontend_http_tcp["http"],
  with aws_lb_listener.frontend_http_tcp["https"],
  in resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp":
```

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko Your current code creates two default actions. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
This work `target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[each.value].arn` but with 
`aws_lb_target_group.main[each.key].arn` instead `each.value`

My next step is working over if `protocol =! TLS` then not use variable `certificate_arn`.

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko Thanks. Answer updated with `each.key`. Not sure, `TLS` is a new issue? If so, a new question could be made.

Comment: Marcin would you mind having a look at this question, please [Terraform set a variable with conditional another variable present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288665/terraform-set-a-variable-with-conditional-another-variable-present).