# Terraform set a variable with conditional another variable present

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-elb

I would like to set a variable only if a value is present.

My variables are:

```
variable "http_tcp_listeners" {
  description = "aws_lb_listener"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    http = {
      # load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.nlb_test.arn
      port        = "80"
      protocol    = "TCP"
      action_type = "forward"
      certificate_arn = ""
      alpn_policy     = ""
    },
    https = {
      # load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.nlb_test.arn
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "TLS"
      action_type = "forward"
      certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:b447fa7953be"
      alpn_policy     = "HTTP2Preferred"
    }
  }
}
```

In case `http` listener the string `alpn_policy = each.value.alpn_policy` should be absent. If the string is just empty `alpn_policy = ""` we will have got error `Error: expected alpn_policy to be one of [HTTP1Only HTTP2Only HTTP2Optional HTTP2Preferred None], got`

If we set any value we will have the error message that `ALPN policy cannot be set for non secure listeners`

I would like something like this. Pseudocode.

```
...
If val.alpn_policy != empty then
  certificate_arn = try(each.value.certificate_arn, false)
  alpn_policy = each.value.alpn_policy
  default_action {
else
  certificate_arn = try(each.value.certificate_arn, false)
  default_action {
...
```

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp" {
  for_each          = var.http_tcp_listeners
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = each.value.port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  certificate_arn = try(each.value.certificate_arn, false)
  alpn_policy = each.value.alpn_policy
  default_action {
    type = each.value.action_type
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[each.key].arn
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main,
    aws_lb_target_group.main,
  ]
}
```

Comment: Given the name of your listener ("frontend_http_tcp") I assume you have checked the terraform-aws-alb module.   They declare two variables (https_listeners and http_tcp_listeners) and then in the module code (main.tf) they keep the separation.    Will that work for you?  or do you have https listeners with and without alpn_policy?

Comment: I also noticed that they use the expression `alpn_policy     = lookup(var.https_listeners[count.index], "alpn_policy", null)`  ... Have you tried this?   Sorry no time to test myself

Comment: In that case, why do you even have `certificate_arn` and `alpn_policy` in http? Why not fully remove them, rather then setting them to empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Thank @RafaP and @Marcin for the ideas. Finally, the code looks like this.
I have deleted unwanted variables in `VAR` and uses [try Function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html) `alpn_policy= try(each.value.alpn_policy, null)`

instead of
`alpn_policy = lookup(var.https_listeners[count.index], "alpn_policy", null)`

```
variable "http_tcp_listeners" {
  description = "aws_lb_listener"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    http = {
      port        = "80"
      protocol    = "TCP"
      action_type = "forward"
    },
    https = {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "TLS"
      action_type = "forward"
      certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:714154805721:certificate/c3be"
      alpn_policy     = "HTTP2Preferred"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "frontend_http_tcp" {
  for_each          = var.http_tcp_listeners
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = each.value.port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol

  certificate_arn = try(each.value.certificate_arn, null)
  alpn_policy     = try(each.value.alpn_policy, null)

  default_action {
    type = each.value.action_type
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.main[each.key].arn
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main,
    aws_lb_target_group.main,
  ]
}
```